# How to convert a column of char datatype into time format in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset which contains some columns in hh:mm:ss format in excel. When I imported this excel sheet in R the columns which where in hh:mm:ss format changed to character.

for example:
This is the column in excel

[image]

And when this excel sheet is imported to R, the column values looks like this

[image]

How do I convert it in the same format as in excel so that I can perform further analysis easily?

Comment: What package-function are you using to read Excel files?

Comment: Try using `lubridate` or `anytime`

Comment: @WenchengLau-Medrano , I am using `read_excel()` function to read excel file

Comment: @Rich That is strange, because this function usually do a good job identifying the column types. I have created by myself an example table in Excel setting one column as time (hour) type, then read it using `read_excel` and it was correctly loaded. But it was neccesary to define it as time-type (hour-type) in Excel before. Of course, you have to remember that a time-only (hour-only) class (in Excel) is internaly a date-time class, so Excel will set some fixed date that then `read_excel` will read, load and show you as POSIX class column.

Comment: @WenchengLau-Medrano , My dataset contains multiple column which is `hh:mm:ss` format in excel but when I read the excel sheet using `read_excel()` few of the columns shows different values (as in problem above) while other columns are properly read . I am not sure why this is happening

Comment: @Rich So I would suggest you to find the way to share with us some example file (just with the date-time columns). Maybe you could upload them in some Github repo and it would be better for us to give you a more specific solution, because it seems that your problem is not so simple to solve after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridateExtras)

# Sample data
df <- tribble(
  ~totalHandling,
  "00:09:24",
  "00:17:28",
  "01:40:20"
)

# Code
df2 <- df |> mutate(totalHandling = hms(totalHandling))
df2
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>   totalHandling
#>   <Period>     
#> 1 9M 24S       
#> 2 17M 28S      
#> 3 1H 40M 20S
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I used mutate function to add new column in my dataframe and used `hms()` as shown in solution but unfortunately it is not working for me. Also, I tried  `df$totalHandling <- hms(df$totalHandling)` but all the values are turned to `NA`.

Comment: If you cut and paste the above example and run only that in a fresh R session, does that work? If not, what error do you get? Presume you have those packages installed?

Comment: Yes, above example works if I copy-paste and run but for my case, for my dataset it's not working